# API Gateway based authentication for OIDC enabled sprint boot APIs

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, api-gateway

We are building a suite of spring boot based microservices deployed in Kubernetes. APIs are authenticated using OIDC protocol and access to APIs is managed through Kong community edition.

There have been suggestion to centralize authentication at API Gateway level. I am all for centralizing the authentication, but I am not able to identify if it really helps simplify the APIs. Authentication is already externalized and APIs still have to validate the JWT token with OIDC provider.

Are there any other benefits of centralized authentication at API Gateway ?

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate the JWT validation to the API Gateway through techniques like introspection. This way your APIs don't have to deal with authn/authz at all. You can also plug new service APIs with ease.